# Cannot install nestJs : "ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE" (re readableHighWaterMark)

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I want to install NestJs/cli on ubuntu 16.4 using the following command,

```
npm install -g @nestjs/cli
```

but unfortunately I get this error

```
87 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@nestjs/cli"
88 verbose node v11.12.0
89 verbose npm  v6.7.0
90 error code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
91 error The value "false" is invalid for option "readableHighWaterMark"
92 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thank you for telling me what this error is and how I should fix it

Answer (score 1):

I have found the error lies inside the node modules
The error is because the cache memory size is not working on large files

To fix on site, I edited one of node modules mentioned in the cache to larger MAX_MEM_SIZE which allows it to work. Still it is a dirty fix

My dirty fix was to edit inside

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/cache.js
```

change

```
const MAX_MEM_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024 // 5MB to become
const MAX_MEM_SIZE = 15 * 1024 * 1024 // 15MB my temp fix to allow large downloads
```

Now npm install nestjs/cli will work!!!

Comment: Is there a more principled solution to this problem?